# Gerar arquivo RES (stringtable) a partir de uma unit resourcestring

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, resources

Estou estudando algumas fontes de como internacionalizar o software, e no exemplo que tenho o software possui uma unit com constantes strings (captions, etc), algo como:

```
unit Resources;
interface
resourcestring
  CompanyName = '***';
implementation
end.
```

E uma outra com os 'IDs' para cada string para depois chamar via:

```
System.SysUtils{$ELSE}SysUtils{$ENDIF}.LoadStr(ID)
```

O projeto possui um arquivo RES, algo como StrConsts.res, que ele chama na diretiva do programa:

```
{$R StrConsts.res}
```

O res possui apenas uma StringTable, com todos os IDs e as strings referentes, o que queria saber é como gerar o arquivo res a partir da unit resourcestring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar um arquivo tipo .res siga os passos abaixo:

1) Crie e salve um arquivo texto com extensão ".rc" com as informações que você deseja. Exemplo: teste.rc

2) No prompt de comando DOS, execute o seguinte comando BRCC32 teste.rc

Observação: O arquivo BRCC32 está disponível no diretório \bin do Delphi.

Comment: Neste caso quais seriam essas informações que eu botaria no arquivo .rc? Eu não queria escrever o STRINGTABLE, mas gerar a partir da unir com a resourcestring.

Comment: Você escolhe quais informações deseja colocar. Se você quer criar um arquivo (.res) para idiomas, deverá colocar variáveis com a legenda original, por exemplo: label1=Nome; label2=Endereço.... ou colocar genéricos que serão identificados, como: lblNome=Nome, lblEndereco=Endereço.... Eu, particularmente, recomendo não criar arquivo .res para idiomas, porque dificulta o usuário de alterar as legendas. Neste caso, qualquer arquivo texto é melhor para o usuário, porque pode editar por qualquer editor de textos.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso que descobri foi olhando os componentes FastReports. Basicamente eles utilizam duas units:

1) frxrcClass.pas = unit contendo as legendas.

2) frxRes.pas = unit com as funções para troca das legendas.

Em cada form ou unit você declara "uses frxClass, frxRes" e pode chamar 
a função Get para trocar cada legenda desejada.

Dê uma olhada, se te interessar, você pode reescrever as funções para seu uso.
Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: eu entendi oq vc escreveu, mas eu estou querendo saber como gerar o arquivo RES.

Answer (score 0):

Pergunta antiga, porém fiz um pequeno software para facilitar o processo de criação de arquivos *.res. Caso ainda seja útil a alguém, o link para o projeto é este: [ResMaker](https://github.com/carlosribeiro1987/resmaker)

Abaixo, prints das janelas do software:

**Janela Principal**
[image: Janela Principal]

**Janela Configurações**
[image: Janela Configurações]